# Angular factory calling async factories randomly fails to execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This factory is randomly failing to execute. JsonReader and ProgressTrack factories are both asynchronous - they read data from files, JsonReader returns a JSON object and ProgressTrack returns an integer, which I use to certain extract data from the JSON object.

While debugging, I think I made the code slow enough that it ran correctly 100% of the time, which leads the to believe I'm not properly waiting for data to be loaded before I start handling it.

If anyone can point out any obvious problem with my code, I'd be very grateful.

Maybe I need to write a promise for both factories and chain them, before handling data from both?

```
angular.module('prgBr', [])
.factory('PrgBr', ['JsonReader', 'ProgressTrack', '$q', function(JsonReader, ProgressTrack, $q) {
    var prgbr = {};
    prgbr.getPrg = function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        JsonReader.get(function(data){
            ProgressTrack.getProgress(function(progress) {
                        var currentEx = progress;
                        var chapEx = progress - 1;
                        var currentChap = data.exercises[chapEx].chapter;
                        var currentTest = data.exercises[currentEx].str1;

                        function arraypush(f) {
                            var chapterarray = [];
                            var idarray = [];
                            chapterarray.push(data.exercises.filter(function(elem) {
                            return elem.chapter===f;
                        }));

                            var idarray = chapterarray[0].map(c=>c.id)
                            var chapexnumber = idarray.length;
                            var exindex = idarray.indexOf(currentEx) + 1;
                            var progbarval = (exindex/chapexnumber)*100;
                            var progbarvalpercent = progbarval + "%";
                            var prgres = {a: progbarval,b: progbarvalpercent};

                            defer.resolve(prgres);
                        };
            arraypush(currentChap);
            });        
        });
    return defer.promise;

    }
    return prgbr;
}]);
```

JsonReader is:

```
angular.module('jsonReader', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonReader', function($resource) {
  return $resource('resources.json');
});
```

Comment: Is there any console error? I see some shabby places but not sure they are causing the issue.

Comment: There is no console error, in debugging I found when the factory fails, nothing logs to console after `JsonReader.get(function(data){`

Comment: Can you show the code of `JsonReader`?

Comment: I've edited the original post with the  code of JsonReader

Comment: Can't help you much, I'm not familiar with `$resource`